# Creating a Project Template Wizard in Visual Studio not allowing me to manually design the Form control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, wizard, project-template

I have followed the steps here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx to create a wizard that allows me to use a custom string when creating a new project from my Visual Studio Template.

But this example adds a textbox to the wizards Form like so:

```
public partial class UserInputForm : Form
{
    private string customMessage;
    private TextBox textBox1;

    public UserInputForm()
    { 
        textBox1 = new TextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(textBox1);
    }

    public string get_CustomMessage()
    {
        return customMessage;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        customMessage = textBox1.Text;
        this.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I want my Dialog to be a little bit more detailed so I have used the Dialog editor to drop a Textbox on like so:

[image]

This causes the following auto generated code to appear:
[image]

Now when I do this I notice that the newly dropped textbox does not appear when I create my project.  Only the one that has been specified in the Constructor like so:
[image]

Why is this so?  I want to add lots of text boxes and labels on the wizard so I don't want to be having to do this all in code in the constructor.

Comment: They kept the example simple.  But a real Form class doesn't look like that, it calls InitializeComponent() in its constructor.  Since you didn't do that, you can't get the textbox either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere along the line, the call to `InitializeComponent` got dropped from your constructor. Just add a call to it and you'll be fine.

By the same token, if you're using the designer, it's bad form to create controls yourself in the constructor. Just add them in the designer.